# show $X^{(0)}$ is a discrete closed subset of $X$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, cw-complexes

If $(X,\mathcal{C})$ is a CW complex, then $X^{(0)}$ is a discrete closed subset of $X$.

---

Let $A\subset X^{0}$. For any cell $c\in\mathcal{C}$, let $X_c$ be a finite subcomplex that contains $\bar{c}$. Note that $A\cap X_c=X_c\setminus(X_c\cap A)$. As $X_c$ is finite, we have $X_c\setminus(X_c\cap A)$ is finite. Additionally, $X$ is Hausdorff, $A\cap X_c=X_c\setminus(X_c\cap A)$ is closed because finite set is closed in Hausdorff space. Thus, $A$ is closed by the weak topology. Moreover, $A\cap\bar{c}=A\cap(X_c\cap\bar{c})$ which is finite.

---

this is what I have so far, and I don't know how to move forward.

---

Edit one: changed discrete finite to discrete closed.

Edit two: found an error in the proof I have, $A\cap X_c$ doesn't eqaul to $X_c\setminus(A\cap X_c)$

Comment: It is not true that the $0$-skeleton is finite in general.  Why are you trying to prove it?

Comment: What is $\mathcal C$? The collection of cells? And why do think that the $0$-skeleton should be finite?

Comment: @EricWofsey it should be discrete closed subset. It's finite if the cell C is finite

Comment: Isn't it true by definition of CW-complexes?